# Setting the App Icon for Google Play?

Tags: android, icons, apk, google-play

Hi I am currently trying to upload a snake game to the Google Play market and I keep getting the error `The icon path specified by the manifest is not in the apk`.

I did not use appcreator, I used eclipse to edit and sign/export the apk. Below is the relevant part of the manifest, but let me know if you need to see more. I DO have an icon.png in the res/drawable folder. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 <application android:label="Crazy Snake">      
      <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon"
          android:name="Snake"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
          <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <receiver android:name="com.Leadbolt.AdNotification" /> 
      <receiver android:name="com.example.android.snake.BootReceiver"> 
          <intent-filter> 
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
          </intent-filter> 
      </receiver>
</application>
```

EDIT: By the way, the icon appears fine on both emulator and phone...

Comment: Hummm.... try refreshing and cleaning your project before signing and exporting it. This has never happened to me :S

Answer (score 1):

Put:

```
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

Here:

```
<application android:label="Crazy Snake"
android:icon="@drawable/icon" > 
...
</application>
```

Comment: this not only still causes google to reject it, but it also makes the icon not appear on the emulator. Is there another method?

Comment: @user1364993 That is strange, any app I've built in eclipse has it's android:icon in the application tag and it displays fine

Answer (score 0):

Put the android:icon="@drawable/icon" inside application tag.

In case if there is other application tag there also you need to put android:icon="@drawable/icon"

Find for empty application tag like  in your manifest, if u find them delete them.